# How do you query for blank schemas?

Tags: oracle, schema

I'm trying to locate blank schemas within my oracle server.

I've tried using `DBA_TAB_COLS`, but no success. Eg:

```
select * from 
( 
  select OWNER, COUNT(distinct(TABLE_NAME)) as TABLE_COUNT 
  from DBA_TAB_COLS 
  group by OWNER 
) 
where TABLE_COUNT = 0
```

Is there a way to query for a list of blank schemas?

Comment: What do you mean by **blank schema**?  A schema which contains no object?

Answer (score 0):

If "blank schema" means a schema that does not own any tables

```
SELECT username
  FROM dba_users u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
      FROM dba_tables t
     WHERE t.owner = u.username
    );
```

If you want to look for schemas that own no object, rather than schemas that own no tables, you'd use `dba_objects` in the subquery rather than `dba_tables`.  For either of these, though, you'd need to have privileges to query the `dba_*` objects.